# Firebase Cloud Function: onUpdate change parameter is wrong went removing value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I have the following cloud function:

```
export const userActicityUpdate = functions.database.ref("/userActivities/{userId}/{objectId}").onUpdate((change, context) => {
    console.log("Before:\n", change.before.val(), "\nAfter:\n", change.after.val())
    return true
})
```

When I have the following data stored at `userActivities/123/321`:

```
{
    "testData": 123
    "moreTestData": 321
    "wow": 321
    "nice": 909
}
```

And then set the data at that node to:

```
{
    "testData": 123
    "moreTestData": 99999321
}
```

I expect the function above to fire once, with the change parameters exactly matching the two pieces of data above. This is **what happens when I deploy** the function and change the data.

**But when I test via the `functions:shell`** from the terminal, I see a different `change.after` snapshot.

I run the function like this:

```
userActicityUpdate({
    before: {testData:123,moreTestData:321,wow:321,nice:909},
    after: {testData:123,moreTestData:99999321}
})
```

And then I see the following output to the console:

> Before:  { testData: 123, moreTestData: 321, wow: 321, nice: 909 }
>
> After:  { testData: 123, moreTestData: 99999321, wow: 321, nice: 909 }

**How come the values `wow` and `nice` is included in the after snapshot, when the data has been removed?**

**How can I reliably test this case?**

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.  In the future, feel free to file a bug report for things like this.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Okay. I've reported the bug now. Thanks :)